# changing Y/n prompt in CLI

Tags: command-line, source-code

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.02 LTS Server.
I want to change the prompt message "Do you want to continue" to "Is this desirable?" how would I do that?

Comment: What's the point? And it depends on the program(s) you are talking about, so please add the program's name. It's absolutely possible if you edit the source code, though.

Comment: There really is no point besides entertainment... also, i want to change it on the command line interface terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt message is individually defined per package. You would be able to change the message if you would edit the source code (if available) of the package you want to change the prompt in, and recompile.